# How to get the latest videos from YouTube watch history

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I want to get the latest videos from [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) watch history. I am using the following code, but the video size is always different and very rarely is equal to 100. How can I resolve this problem?

```cs
YouTubeRequestSettings ytSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(AppKey, DevKey, currentLogin, currentPassword);
ytSettings.PageSize = 10;
ytSettings.AutoPaging = true;
YouTubeRequest ytRequest = new YouTubeRequest(ytSettings);

string uri = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_history?v=2";
Feed<Video> videos = ytRequest.Get<Video>(new Uri(uri));
List<string> vids = new List<string>();

foreach (Video vid in videos.Entries)
{
    if (vids.Count < 100)
    {
        vids.Add(vid.VideoId.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me, could you try using a different feed (such as `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/most_viewed?v=2`) to see if the issue still exists?

Comment: I tried it 5 times with https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/most_viewed?v=2 feed and it works fine for me. (vids size always was 99). But with watch history feed vids size was 100, 18, 80, 100, 0

Comment: That makes me think that this is an issue with the API itself, so your post in the YouTube API Forum is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pasting the link so that someone might find it useful for their knowledge

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143669/Manage-YouTube-using-C-and-Youtube-API

**Update:** 
Hi I got the links from google developers . There are four methods defined there for .NET . so we've to dig ourselves about recent uploads . As I can't see any recent videos headings for .NET

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet